# ¿Cuál es la mejor traducción para 'fitting' cuando hablamos de costura y patrones?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral

A ver costureros, patronistas, modistas, sastres, diseñadores de modas, etc. Cuando hay un problema de patrón o de entalle que necesita arreglarse, se habla de 'fitting correction' en inglés. Y 'fit' funciona perfectamente como 'ajustar' o 'entallar' en lo que tiene que ver con prendas de ropa. En ningún momento se pretende dar la idea de 'adecuado'. Entonces, si hablo de 'fitting correction', ' fitting video', 'fitting demonstration', traduciría corrección/video/demo de ajuste, arreglo o de entalle? Cómo se dice en el país donde viven? He visto libros y videos usando ambas, pero quisiera saber cuál es más universal.

Comment: Falta citar los ejemplos de donde sacaste esos términos, por lo que veo ni siquiera en inglés existe algo llamado como ' fitting video' o 'fitting demonstration'

Comment: Se trata de probar la ropa.

Comment: Esta pregunta está dando vueltas y mas vuelttas.

Comment: @Lambie Apenas ha sido "bumped" por Community user [bot] 4 veces. En Web Applications Stack Exchange tenemos cada hora preguntas que llevan 10 o mas vences siendo "bumped". Esto pasa porque hay respuestas que no tienen votos. Solución: Hay que votar, positivo o negativo. También "funcionaría" cerrar la pregunta o borrarla pero en algunos casos eso sería un despropósito. Cerrar o borrar sólo deberá usarse cuando eso sea apropiado considerando la reglas vigentes.

Comment: @Rubén Ya he votado. Negativo. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Ajuste** es la más universal, de hecho en vídeo, la señal que se utiliza para calibración de pantalla se llama *señal de ajuste*, *carta de ajuste* o en última instancia, *pantalla de ajuste*:

[image]

*[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_de_ajuste)*

Si el *fitting video* es acerca del ensamble de un producto, la traducción es **vídeo de montaje**. Como ejemplo, la página *https://helpemup.com* tiene un menú *Fitting* con varias opciones. En un español universal, todas se traducirían como *montaje*:

[image]

De arriba a abajo:

- Montaje
- Montando el arnés
- Diagrama del montaje
- Montando el accesorio de paseo a su arnés.

En Español, el término fitting aplicado a costura suele englobarse al verbo *probar* y sus derivados tales como *prueba* o *probador*.

En el ejemplo del menú de [styleme.com](https://style.me/virtual-fitting/), ambos menús se traducirían:

- Probador Virtual
- Demostración del probador

[image]

> ¿Qué es un ‘fitting’?
> Son **pruebas**, para un estilista es su día de más trabajo, porque todos los looks que has estado creando sobre papel, en tu cabeza… los llevas a la realidad

<sub>*Fuente [Lavanguardia.com](https://www.lavanguardia.com/de-moda/pasarelas/20160201/301816284496/que-es-un-fitting-la-parte-mas-importante-de-un-desfile.html)*</sub>

Comment: Se trata de moda y ropas.

Comment: Here is a comparison between "fitting" and "proper". https://www.ingles.com/comparar/fitting/proper

Answer (score 0):

En español aparentemente no tenemos un concepto único que exprese los distintos aspectos que en inglés actualmente recoge la palabra "*fitting*", ya que el término "fitting" por si solo abarca un espectro más amplio y distintos entornos.

Las traducciones más habituales para "fitting" son: *apto, entallado, a propósito, a medida, apropiado, accesorios, disposición, conexiones, acondicionamiento, arreglos, terminaciones, equipamiento*...

A esto hay que añadir que el término "fitting", según en que contextos, se ha expandido y refleja en ocasiones otras acepciones que van más allá de la actividad donde se aplica.

En moda simplemente decimos "**te queda bien o esta a tu medida**", y cuando se habla de "**fitting**" **se refiere al desarrollo organizativo que existe de manera preliminar al evento público o de exhibición de algunas campañas, desfiles o ferias de la moda donde se pueden apreciar el conjunto de los trabajos realizados por los diseñadores y estilistas.**

No obstante, los otros aspectos de "fitting", permiten que se pueda hablar de;

- **fitting correction** ( ejem. guía especial de ayuda para ajustar y corregir profesionalmente el color de imágenes,  estados financieros adaptados a la realidad económica y financiera de una empresa, de un país, el entalle que necesita arreglarse o adaptarse a un modelo de forma expresa en un momento dado...)
- **fitting video** (video apto o adaptado para un determinado público objetivo, empresa, gremio, fin, demostraciones cientificas... que se muestran las posibles ventajas)
- **fitting demonstration** (ejem. se prepara un encuentro con modelos que sirven para explicar y dar a conocer un determinado producto u objeto y como este es capaz de adaptarse según las necesidades de cada persona )
- **fitting de moda** (**desde el corte, ajuste y entalle de una prenda hasta como lleva esa prenda o la luce cada modelo**). En español "fitting" viene a ser "quedar bien" aplicado a la ropa.
- **fitting vino** (*industrial*, adaptación de la maquinaria, y *social*, adaptación de los vinos a los distintos platos y sabores.)
- **fitting test** (prueba de variedad de objetos, movimientos, entornos... para encontrar el mejor que se adapte al lugar donde se desarrolle la actividad)
- fitting room (probador)
- **fitting golf** (adaptación exclusiva del material utilizado a las características del jugador)
- fitting ...

Sin embargo, los "*fitting*" en estos contextos poseen un denominador común que hacen referencia a un tipo de proceso, donde se busca adaptar y modificar apropiadamente la actividad correspondiente que se va a desarrollar y donde lo que se pretende obtener es un resultado razonable, acorde a las determinadas situaciones o circunstancias individuales expresadas.

En español utilizaríamos varios sinónimos como justo, conveniente, encajado, acomodado, ajustado, acoplado, apropiado, a propósito, a medida, apto, formal....empero desde mi punto de vista, en español también sería apto utilizar una única expresión para todo ello. Una expresión bastante utilizada y acorde a las situaciones y contextos expresados, así podemos decir, "**ad hoc**" en el sentido de "**hecho a la medida**", "**a medida**", "**personalizado**" para;

- **corrección ad hoc** (en moda seria la forma expresa para corregir algo en un momento preciso o bajo una técnica concreta eventualmente necesario ya sea para un arreglo, una adaptación... que hacen referencia a situaciones concretas dentro del diseño o de un desfile. Por otra parte, en moda también se utiliza la expresión latina “*Ad Libitum*” que significa con libertad, a voluntad, a elección a gusto. La moda Adlib).
- **video ad hoc** (video adaptado o realizado de forma expresa teniendo en cuenta las características de una institución, un gremios, un particular...).
- **demostración ad hoc** (demostración de un producto, objeto, una manera de hacer... que atiende de manera especial a algo específico ).
- **moda ad hoc** (moda, patrones, prendas, formas que abordan de manera especial una imagen... centrada en una línea concreta del estilismo, modelos, diseñadores...)
- **vino ad hoc** (Realización de aspectos industriales o sociales que tiene en cuenta las características propias de cada región, situación, localización, temperatura y aquello que le circunscribe en el mundo vinícola)
- **golf ad hoc** (se determinan las característica propias para adaptar el equipo y técnicas de juego al jugador, con el fin de obtener el mayor rendimiento).
- ...

---

Definición **ad hoc**

*Expresión latina que significa que es apropiado, adecuado o especialmente dispuesto para un determinado fin.*

"*se le advirtió que había muerto, y en voz alta, dio la absolución y pronunció las oraciones ad hoc*"

*Que está hecho especialmente para un fin determinado o pensado para una situación concreta.*

"*solución ad hoc*"*

---

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

**Ad hoc**

> ad hoc. Loc. lat. (pron. [ad-ók], no [ad-hók]) que significa
> literalmente ‘para esto’. Se emplea como locución adjetiva con el
> sentido de ‘adecuado, apropiado, dispuesto especialmente para un fin’:
> «Guardando el cable en el compartimento ad hoc» (CInfante Habana [Cuba
> 1986]); y como locución adverbial, con el sentido de ‘a propósito para
> la ocasión’: «El lugar adecuado para dar explicaciones es la comisión
> creada ad hoc en esta Cámara» (Mundo [Esp.] 15.6.95)...

https://www.rae.es/dpd/ad%20hoc

---

**Ad hoc**

> 1​ es una locución latina2​ que significa literalmente «para
> esto».3​
>
> Generalmente se refiere a una solución específicamente elaborada para
> un problema o fin preciso y, por tanto, no generalizable ni utilizable
> para otros propósitos.
>
> En sentido amplio, ad hoc en el mundo científico se llama a algo que
> es una excepción a la ley establecida, por ejemplo se añade un
> tribunal por fuera del sistema ordinario para un caso específico...

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc

Comment: Aqui, se trata de ropas y moda. El resto no tiene nada que ver.

Comment: @Lambie, la pregunta desde mi punto de vista esta mal redactada. Desde el principio tuve la misma sensación, sin embargo cuando dice " Entonces, si hablo de 'fitting correction', ' fitting video', 'fitting demonstration', traduciría corrección/video/demo de ajuste, arreglo o de entalle? " parece que el mismo concepto que para la moda utiliza lo quiere llevar a otros campos y ante mi duda expuse ambas consideraciones, sin saber muy bien a que atenerme, ya que como digo la pregunta en si es bastante deficiente en su redacción. De todas formas gracias por la observación.

Comment: Your answers are much too long for these simple questions and I get lost trying to follow the arguments. :)